# Search usernames with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

At the moment I'm trying to use a regular expression to find usernames. The following condition is what I need:
"Username matches the search term with a maximum of 3 wrong characters"

For example,
Database content:

- "MyUsername"

Search command -> returning match:

- search("Username") -> "MyUsername"
- search("Us3rname") -> "MyUsername"
- search("userName") -> "MyUsername"
- search("MyUser") -> none (4 characters wrong)
- search("My Us3r N@me") -> none (4 characters wrong)

I can build my regex dynamically and push this to a database query. I only can't get a grip on the regex itself. Could you help me with this? Would be great? (or is it even possible?)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with regular expression. You need some similarity algorithm to check the similarity between two strings.

A good start and an easy one is the [levensthein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

In short: It calculates how many Insert/Update/Delete Operations are needed to transform string A to string B.

I had done this in Javascript some years ago, but it should be easy in nearly every programming language. You can find a working example [here](http://www.kurzhals.info/static/samples/levenshtein_distance/):

```
// http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};

Array.min = function( array ){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};

// Levenshstein Distance Calculation
function levenshtein_distance (t1, t2) {
    var countI = t1.length+1;
    var countJ = t2.length+1;

    // build empty 'matrix'
    var matrix = new Array (countI);
    for (var i=0;i<countI;i++) {
        matrix[i] = new Array (countJ);
    }

    // initialize the matrix;
    // set m(0,0) = 0;
    // m(0,0<=j<countJ) = j
    // m(0<=i<countI, 0) = i
    matrix[0][0] = 0;
    for (var j=1;j<matrix[0].length;j++) {
        matrix[0][j] = j;
    }
    for (var i=1;i<matrix.length;i++) {
        matrix[i][0] = i;
    }

    // calculate the matrix
    for (var i=1;i<matrix.length;i++) {
        for (var j=1;j<matrix[i].length;j++) {
            var costs = new Array ();
            if (t1.charAt(i-1) == t2.charAt(j-1)) {
                costs.push (matrix[i-1][j-1]);
            }
            costs.push (matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1);
            costs.push (matrix[i][j-1] + 1);
            costs.push (matrix[i-1][j] + 1);
            matrix[i][j] = Array.min(costs);
        }
    }

    // resultMatrix = matrix;
    var result = new Object
    result.distance = matrix[countI-1][countJ-1];
    result.matrix = matrix;
    return result;
}
```